# C# Return IDataReader nothing

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two code. One is working and the other one is not working for some reason. And the one which works, does not return all rows.

Not working:

```
public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetSomeData(string queryText)
{
    using (MySqlConnection cn = CreateConnection())
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryText, cn))
        {
            using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    yield return rdr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Working

```
public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetSomeData(string queryText)
{
    using (MySqlConnection cn = CreateConnection())
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryText, cn))
        {
            using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                foreach (IDataRecord record in rdr as IEnumerable)
                {
                    yield return record;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many rows does the one that "works" return? 1?

Comment: One row, there is two rows. When i print log message reader itself see 2 rows. But when i yield return it. I get Only the last one.